# Excel Conditional formatting to highlight other cell based on another cells text. Specifically a letter tied to a string of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a cell with a string of numbers like this: 11254S987. Other subsequent cells may have a deferent letter mixed in the string of numbers. I want to highlight other cells based on the letter "S" in the cell mentioned. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the cells that you want to format.
2. Under the Conditional Formatting dropdown, select add a new rule
3. In the formula bar, enter: `=FIND("S",A1)>0` (see screenshot)

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

What this does, is conditional format the cell in column B, if the corresponding cell in column A has the letter `S` in it

Comment: Thanks!!!! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Josh you can mark the answer as accepted, by clicking the check mark and making it turn green